# Communication through deep space in Halo

Tags: space, halo, communication

In universes like Halo, where civilizations span hundreds of planets/moons etc. How would they be able to reliably communicate without having extreme latency? Is there some sort of "reasonable sci-fi" way to explain this? I'm not exactly harping at any scientific plot holes, just wondering if there is some sort of grounds for a possible explanation.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Halo, or just in general? I think this will be too broad unless you're asking about a single work of fiction.

Comment: @F1Krazy I guess I'm really just asking about Halo, but I was wondering if the answer for them could be theoretically possible in our world

Comment: If you want to ask Halo explains it, that would be on-topic ([though trivial](https://halofanon.fandom.com/wiki/Faster-than-light_communication)). Asking about real world science is off-topic here.

Comment: @Harabeck oh okay well then I guess you answered my question. Should I delete this post? I don't want to be that guy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Halo universe has established FTL travel, known as Slipstream Space, or Slipspace.

> Slipstream space ... is a dimensional subdomain of alternate spacetime consisting of eleven non-visible infinitesimal dimensions used for faster-than-light travel.

[Slipstream Space (Halopedia)](https://www.halopedia.org/Slipstream_space)

While there are a few francishes that break this rule, FTL travel usually implies FTL communication. Simply imagine that it's radio signals being transited across Slipspace, instead of physical objects.

If for some reason radio signals couldn't be transmitted in that way, you would simply encode your message onto an physical, electronic storage medium of some sort, and send it across Slipspace instead. Halo specifically used the latter method (ships carrying information) until they figured out how to transmit signals in a similar way using what they called Wavespace.

Wavespace however was very energy intensive, and prone to distortion. A race known as the Forerunners were considered masters of Slipspace travel, and had developed the ability to send signals over Slipspace directly. Humans later developed this technology for their own ships.

> Using Forerunner technology, signals can instead be carried across slipspace, allowing colonies and even starships to remain in contact at much faster speeds. UNSC Infinity's superluminal communications capability includes 16-channel "slipspace wavecom datalinks"

[Superluminal communications (Halopedia)](https://www.halopedia.org/Superluminal_communications)